# Duvida na API SendBird para criar um chat

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mobile

Boa noite pessoal,

Estou fazendo um projetinho e estou utilizando a API do SendBird para criar um chat, porem estou encontrando problemas ao receber a mensagem que foi enviada de um usuário para outro, poderiam me ajudar? 
Segue abaixo o código para receber a mensagem

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //passa o token de conexão para o programa
        SendBirdClient.Init(APP_ID);

        //esse 1 é o id do usuário que está cadastrado na minha deshboard
        SendBirdClient.Connect("1", (User user, SendBirdException e) =>
        {
            if (e != null)
            {
                // Error
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //Receber mensagens
                GroupChannel.GetChannel("sendbird_group_channel_67663307_ced62c9c4460ceb0db9d26297e2528617d883552", (GroupChannel groupChannel, SendBirdException ex3) =>
                {
                    if (e != null)
                    {
                        // Error!
                        return;
                    }

                    // Successfully fetched the channel.
                    // Do something with groupChannel.
                    else
                    {
                        SendBirdClient.ChannelHandler ch = new SendBirdClient.ChannelHandler();
                        ch.OnMessageReceived = (BaseChannel baseChannel, BaseMessage baseMessage) =>
                        {
                            // Received a chat message

                        };
                        SendBirdClient.AddChannelHandler(UNIQUE_HANDLER_ID, ch);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual problema está ocorrendo? Parece que a mensagem chegará em `ch.OnMessageReceived`

Comment: Não estou conseguindo exibir o resultado dessa linha em uma string por exemplo para poder usar na minha aplicação, eu também pensei que o ch.OnMessageReceived fosse a mensagem só que perceba que está comentado dentro dele "Received a chat message", da a entender que é para pegar o resultado da mensagem ali

Comment: Faça este teste: Você colocou um breakpoint nesta linha, e o breakpoint é atingido?

Comment: Sim, acabei de fazer, procurei por algum resultado esperado dentro dos métodos no breakpoint e não encontrei nada :/